# Extending the lifetime of a temporary value in C++

Tags: c++, reference, temporary

```
const int &ra=3;
```

1. As I know, making `ra` const will extends the lifetime of the temporary r-value which is in this case 3. This is a little bit confusing, as I know `ra` should have the same address as r-value which is here 3, but 3 is not a real variable and it does not have a memory where it's stored. So how can this be possible?
2. what is the difference between:

   ```
   const int& ra=a;
   ```

   and

   ```
   int& const ra=a;
   ```

Comment: Besides the fact that `int& const ra=a;` is not valid C++ you mean...

Comment: @Addessamad - The compiler can also handle `const int a = 3;`. There is not much of a difference here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> but 3 is not a real variable and it does not have a memory where it's stored. so how can this be possible ?

Actually a temporary object gets created out of the literal `3`, and then that temporary is bound to the const reference. That is how it becomes possible.

---

Now your next question: the difference between these two

```
const int& ra=a;
int& const ra=a;
```

is that the second statement is illegal.

Comment: @Nawaz : for the 1st question. does the int() function is the one respensible for returning a temporary object. like this int(3) so a temporary object get created

Comment: @Nawaz and why we can do *const int &ra=3;* and can't *int &ra=3;* ?

Comment: @AbdessamadBond: There is no `int()` function. The compiler creates the temporary object, without create such imaginary functions.

Comment: Is `int& const` even legal C++?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Ohh. I realized that isn't legal to begin with.

Comment: @Nawaz if there is not function called int() why int(3) works ?

Comment: @AbdessamadBond: That is casting.`int(3)` is same as `(int)3`.

Comment: @AbdessamadBond: The language defines what is valid syntax and what is not, together with the semantics of it. The fact that it looks like a function call does not mean that it is.

Comment: int& const is not valid. int const& is the same as const int& and actually I prefer the first notation.

Answer (score 8):

1) Whether or not the compiler decides to actually *store* your number `3` is a detail subject to optimisation decisions. As far as the language is concerned, the temporary object lives as long as the reference. Practically, if you only need the *value* (not the *object*), the object may never be stored at all, and instead the compiler may substitute the value directly whenever you use `ra`. Of course, if you take the address (via `&ra`), then the compiler will make sure that an object is actually stored somewhere so that you can take its address. (It may still substitute the value directly elsewhere, rather than loading it from that address.)

2) The second version isn't valid C++. You can only say `int const & x` and `const int & x`, for the same reason that `int const` and `const int` denote the same type. The reference itself has no notion of constancy; it is always bound to the object with which it is initialized (i.e. you can't have a "naked" reference object <s>`int & x;`</s>).

Comment: and why we can do *const int &ra=3;* and can't *int &ra=3;* ?

Comment: @Alecs: That's just a design decision of the language. It would almost always be conceptually wrong to modify a temporary object, so you're just not allowed to. If it were allowed, people would write terrible code.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, when you make a variable const, it's allocated a memory where it's stored, like any other variable. Depending on the compiler, if you place that const 3 in a function, it might allocate a temp 3 every time you call the function, or it might just reference a static value allocated when the program started. That 3 is a real variable in that it's data that's been stored somewhere, just like every other variable.

However, referencing that value outside of its scope is going to be a crapshoot as to whether or not it will work, and so you shouldn't use that as a way to "extend the life" of a variable. You might get lucky and have the const be allocated in a static place, and so you'll always get the value you want, even when you access it out of scope; but you might get unlucky, and end up grabbing data that's written over the temp value you wanted. The behavior is "undefined" - that means compilers decide how they want to do it, so there's no way you can count on. Instead, increase the scope of the variable by declaring it earlier, or allocating it on heap (`int* x = malloc(sizeof(int))//, etc.` and passing its pointer around.